# What are iPhone 7(new) screen Resolution, Pixel and Size?

Tags: ios, iphone

Apple announced release of iPhone 7 recently.

What are iPhone 7's Screen resolution,pixel and size?

I searched on Google but I can't find any answer for it.

Comment: you can get this in iPhone 7 - [Technical Specifications](http://www.apple.com/iphone-7/specs/)

Comment: Really? You didn't find anything on Google? [Really?](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=iphone%207%20screen%20resolution&rct=j)

Comment: What is “Google”? @NSNoob :))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**iPhone 7**

- resolution= 750x1334
- Logical resolution: 375x667
- Ppi: 326 ppi
- Aspect ratio: 9:16
- Size diagonal:4.7 inch

---

**iPhone 7 Plus**

- resolution= 1242x2208
- Logical resolution: 414x736
- Ppi: 401 ppi
- Aspect ratio: 9:16
- Size diagonal:5.5 inch

Comment: So that's what they call it... **'Logical resolution'**. Thank you!